# How to get rows having same column data in 2 different dataFrames in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 different DataFrames:

```
df1
```

```
    col1 col2 col3
 0   d1    p1  k1
 1   d2    p2  k2
 2   s1    s2  k3
 3   s3    s4  k4
```

```
df2
```

```
     col3 col4 col3
 0   d1    p1  m1
 1   d2    p2  m2
 2   f1    f2  m3
 3   f3    f4  m4
 4   f5    g2  m5
```

The result that I want is - rows having the same 1st 2 column values. In the example above, that is the rows `d1, p1` and `d2, p2`:

```
      col col
 0   d1    p1
 1   d2    p2
```

How can this be achieved? I tried using `concat`, `merge`, and `drop` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both df's are of same length

try:

```
mask=(df1[['col1', 'col2']].values==df2[['col3', 'col4']].values).all(1)
```

Finally pass that mask either to df1 or to df2:

```
df1[mask]
#OR
df2[mask]
```

output of above code:

```
    col3    col4
0   d1      p1
1   d2      p2
```

Comment: i am getting this error -AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: i updated my DF in the question , please suggest 1 more time

Comment: @suresh in this case my solution will not work since the length of both dataframes are different use merge method as answered by Shaido but before that use `df2.columns=[f'col{x}'for x in range(3,len(df.columns)+2)]`

Comment: thanks for the reply, any other suggestion would be really appreciated @Anurag

Comment: @suresh firstly rename columns of df2 because `'col3'` is duplicate...i.e there are 2 entries of `col3` in columns of df2 so use `df2.columns=[f'col{x}'for x in range(3,len(df.columns)+2)]` or `df.columns=['col3', 'col4', 'col5']` and then use answer given by Shaido

Comment: Working fine with merge suggestion, thanks a lot @Anurag

Answer (score 0):

If the rows with the same values can be on different rows (i.e., row 1 in `df1` can match row 4 in `df2`) then you can simply use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['col1', 'col2'], right_on=['col3', 'col4'])[['col1', 'col2']]
```

Result:

```
  col1  col2
0   d2    p2
1   d1    p1
```